# json_encode() if the number of elements in the array more then 3

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array that contains the following elements:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(2) { ["home"]=> string(5) "Niort" ["away"]=> string(12) "Valenciennes" } 
  [1]=> array(2) { ["home"]=> string(15) "Kuban Krasnodar" ["away"]=> string(3) "Ufa" } 
  [2]=> array(2) { ["home"]=> string(17) "Fratangelo, Bjorn" ["away"]=> string(13) "Bhambri, Yuki" } 
  [3]=> array(2) { ["home"]=> string(13) "VfL Wolfsburg" ["away"]=> string(15) "Bayern Mnchen" } 
}
```

And I am trying to convert it to a JSON array with:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push($events, $row);
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

It does not work.
However, when I reduce the number of elements to 3 or less, it works perfectly.

Why is this happening? How can I convert more items?

Comment: json_encode *does* work, for any arbitrary sized arrays. It might just not work 'as expected'. But since the actual output is not shown (as are not the expected results) ..

Comment: What do you mean under 'as expected'? From that line - `echo json_encode($events);` i expect (in my case) the following output: `[{"home":"Niort","away":"Valenciennes"},{"home":"Kuban Krasnodar","away":"Ufa"},{"home":"Fratangelo, Bjorn","away":"Bhambri, Yuki"}{"home":"VfL Wolfsburg","away":"Bayern Mnchen"}]` but i don't get it :) and I do not get any other information which would pointed on my mistake. However when I try to do the same with fewer elements I get the  'expected' result.

Comment: json_encode will handle anything you throw at it, as long as there's enough memory available to build the json string. it couldn't care less how many or few elements are in an array. if you had a trillion item array and enough memory to hold that, json_encode will encode it for you.

Comment: I formatted the code and did some grammar proofing. This post could be further improved by describing what exactly "does not work", and how the failure happens.

Comment: Error message would be welcome. Consider enabling it so we could help you.

Comment: In that case I do not get error messages. Just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Your php array and code should look like this:**

```
<?php

$array1= array(
array( "home"=>  "Niort" ,"away"=>  "Valenciennes" ), 
array( "home"=>  "Kuban Krasnodar", "away"=>  "Ufa" ), 
array( "home"=>  "Fratangelo, Bjorn", "away"=>  "Bhambri, Yuki" ), 
array( "home"=>  "VfL Wolfsburg", "away"=>  "Bayern Mnchen" ) 
);

echo json_encode($array1);
```

Comment: I tried to convert my array to your variant and i got the same results.

Comment: @IvanDenisovich i am getting this result `[{"home":"Niort","away":"Valenciennes"},{"home":"Kuban Krasnodar","away":"Ufa"},{"home":"Fratangelo, Bjorn","away":"Bhambri, Yuki"},{"home":"VfL Wolfsburg","away":"Bayern Mnchen"}]`
is that your expected result?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result. The problem probably is that I have not enough memory as answered above.

Comment: @IvanDenisovich Restart your server and try again.